# " An object reference is required to access non-static member" error when using static

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, static-methods

I have made a method (changePaddleSize) in the class"Paddle", and trying to call it from another class "paddleMinimizer". When doing this, I get the following error:

> An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Component.transform'

Here are my classes:

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

 public static void changePaddleSize(){

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(2f, 0.5f, 1);

   }
}
```

and

```
public class paddleMinimizer : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject triggerText;
void OnCollisionEnter () {
    Paddle.changePaddleSize ();

  }

}
```

I have obviously done something wrong, but how can I fix this? If there is another way of doing this, please tell me. It will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `changePaddleSize` function is static, but the `transform` property it's trying to access is not. It could be that your `paddleMinimizer` object should have a reference to a specific `Paddle`, or perhaps that your `Paddle` class could use a singleton pattern.

Comment: Could you try to edit my code to give me a better perspective? I'm relatively new to Unity and c#.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only ever going to be one Paddle, one option might be to declare a static var that is the Paddle, and reference as such from within your code.

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Paddle global;

    void Awake () {
        Paddle.global = GetComponent<Paddle>();
    }

    public static void changePaddleSize(){
        Paddle.global.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2f, 0.5f, 1);
    }

}
```

This way you can still call `Paddle.changePaddleSize ();` from anywhere and have it work.

---

Alternatively, you could have `changePaddleSize` *not* be a static method, and call `Paddle.global.changePaddleSize()` instead:

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Paddle global;

    void Awake () {
        Paddle.global = GetComponent<Paddle>();
    }

    public void changePaddleSize(){
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(2f, 0.5f, 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: In my breakout game I have 3 lifes. On my first life nothing happens to my Paddle, but when I die and a new paddle is instantiated, your code works and the paddle minimizes. Why is that?

Comment: @tomSurge Sounds like it works because when a new paddle is created, its `Awake` method replaces `Paddle.global` with the new paddle that's just been instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Component you want to work on the transform from. You will get this from the GameObject you are working with. You can use

```
GameObject.Find("name")
```

Or

```
GameObject.FindWithTag("tagName")
```

Then as long as the game object is not null you can:

```
myGameObject.GetComponent<T>()
```

Where T is your component type. Again this could return null so you must check for this.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this, but could you edit my code to correspond with what you said? I am new to Unity and c#

Comment: Think you need to understand when and where to use static classes. Have you read up on c#? How many paddles are you expecting at any one time?